# Different renderers for datagrid in flex 4.0

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I'm working in flex 4.0 and I have a data grid with three columns. The second column should display the selection(s) the user has made according to the these rules: if they selected only one name display a label with the name in that grid cell, if they chose more than one name then a drop down list should be displayed with a title "Multiple Selected" and the drop down when clicked will show all the names associated for that entry. Therefore the second column can have a mixture of labels and drop down lists. As an example the first entry they chose only one person, so for the first row the second column it shows a label with the person's name. Then in the second entry say they chose 2 names, the second row second column shows a drop down list with the two names in the drop down list. As you can see the second column has a label and a drop down list mixture. Note the selection process is not taking place in the datagrid, the information is simply being supplied by means of setting the dataprovider for the datagrid.

Comment: Not really sure if there is a question in here, but every column has both a labelFunction and an itemRenderer property which are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out you make a itemrenderer with both the label and the dropdown list but you disable one while enabling the other when the conditions are met. The only problem with this approach is I modify the width as well because the label comes first and pushes the drop down list to the right (even when it isn't visible and sometimes beyond the width of the column). So I adjust the widths of each component (setting one to 100% while the other is 0% depending on which is to be visible) but for some reason when I update the data it does not immediately change the cell, only if I click on the header does it change the width and the visibility. I think this is because the UI does not commit the width adjusts immediately? I know it's the width because if I comment out the width adjustments once my data gets updated you see the change right away in the datagrid. For instance if I have not chosen yet the names of my selection, the cell is blank. Then I make a selection of just one person then it shows right away the name in the cell using the label component. Then if I select another name the data gets updated again and you see in the data cell some space (this is the label thats invisible but has some text which causes some empty space) and the drop down list with the names of the ones selected and again it's an immediately effect I don't have to click on the grid to update it. Here's the code with the width adjustments uncommented:

```
                                protected function mxdatagriditemrenderer1_dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                                {
                                    if(data.judgmentpart.JudgmentDebtors.length ==1)
                                    {//display label and disable the dropdown list
                                        lblData.visible = true;
                                        lblData.enabled = true;
                                        lblData.percentWidth = 100;
                                        DDLdatagrid.visible = false;
                                        DDLdatagrid.enabled = false;
                                        DDLdatagrid.percentWidth = 0;
                                    }
                                    else if (data.judgmentpart.JudgmentDebtors.length >1)
                                    {
                                        lblData.visible = false;
                                        lblData.enabled = false;
                                        lblData.percentWidth = 0;
                                        DDLdatagrid.visible = true;
                                        DDLdatagrid.enabled = true;
                                        DDLdatagrid.percentWidth = 100;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        lblData.visible = false;
                                        lblData.enabled = false;
                                        lblData.percentWidth = 0;
                                        DDLdatagrid.visible = false;
                                        DDLdatagrid.enabled = false;
                                        DDLdatagrid.percentWidth = 0;
                                    }
                                }

                                protected function mxdatagriditemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                                {
                                    lblData.visible = false;
                                    lblData.enabled = false;
                                    lblData.percentWidth = 0;
                                    DDLdatagrid.visible = false;
                                    DDLdatagrid.enabled = false;
                                    DDLdatagrid.percentWidth = 0;
                                }

                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>
                        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:Label id="lblData" text="{data.judgmentpart.JudgmentDebtors}"
                                     />
                            <s:DropDownList id="DDLdatagrid" dataProvider="{data.judgmentpart.JudgmentDebtors}"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                    </s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Just set the dataprovider again and it worked (JudgmentDisplay is the datagrid id): JudgmentDisplay.dataProvider = JR;